# Email Template HTML & CSS (email client) compatibility

Tags: java, node.js, email, coldfusion, email-templates

is there any library available in nodejs,coldfusion or java.
if i can use for checking template compatibility for email clients.

for example im sending email campaign before sending i want to check, if current  template CSS+HTML code  is good for outlook, mobile, google mail  and other clients ..

i want to show suggestions to user like " In current template some css styles not compatible for outlook it may change layout"

so far im searching these tags in template and showing result

```
$attribute
$attribute="$value"
E:link  
E:visited   
E:active
some more...
```

compatible in Outlook & yahoo Not in Gmail and AOL
im looking solution if easy way to do rather then i build my own library if something available already.

Thanks guys any advice will be really helpful.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: im already searching in my code and showing my results i just posted here because i wanted to make this process easy for me.  right now  building my own databse just wanted to make sure im not re-inventing wheel & find  right way to do im not guru you guys are...

Comment: @M.A You're not posting anything helpful we can use to help you. By code we mean html code from your campaign, including the CSS. In email development, we use devices such as Outlook email client or devices such as an iPhone 8 to see the results. Beyond that, we use tools like Litmus or Email on Acid.

Comment: @gwally Thank you so much... litmus im also using problem is it is manual work my issue is everything is dynamic like some how if i can so process dynamic need advice..

Comment: Litmus is automated and not manual work, the screenshots they provide is by vm's (I think).